# jQuery form validation does not work/plug in

Tags: jquery, html, validation

I can not make my jQuery validation work. It actually works in an online compiler so I suspect I did not just plug it in correctly. Here is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#CustSubmitForm').validate({
        rules: {
            CustId: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 2
            },
            PaymentSum: {
                required: true,
                number: true,
                minlength: 5
            }
        },

        messages: {
            CustId: "Enter valid ID",
            PaymentSum: "Enter valid sum"
        }
    });
});
```

Those are scripts I have included:

```
src="/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.js"
src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.js"
```

Could someone please answer what might cause the problem? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Fortunately, I found the answer. The thing is that there is a "~/bundles/jqueryval") bundler in the BundleConfig. Jquery validation is included into in by default. So, to get the validation worked, you need to plug it in on the Layout page:@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")